# Android app not minimizing as expected when clicking the home button

Tags: java, android, react-native

**The Problem:**

I have a React-native app, with a third party payment gateway sitting on top of it. My app needs launchMode in the manifest to be set like this:

```
 android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

In the app itself, everything works as expected, but as soon as the third party payment activity is launched, an issue arises.

In this activity, if you minimize the app using the home button, and then launch the app again *from the app drawer*, the app restarts instead of resuming on the payment activity as expected.

However, if you set the launchMode in the manifest to :

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

it works as expected i.e resumes the activity (with a caveat).

The caveat is that if the app launches via ADB or via the Play store (ie. not clicked from the app drawer) the same issue occurs. However, if you start the app from the app drawer, everything works as expected.

I need the launch mode to be single task though, and this bug is really puzzling me at the moment.

I was wondering if anyone has experienced this before and if someone could perhaps share some light on this issue. I unfortunately can't share too much of the code, but it's mostly standard stuff.

Comment: `adb shell dumpsys activity` might help you debug this. It will let you view the current activity stacks, and the intents with which the activities were started.